# History Question - Branch Cut

Tags: complex-analysis, math-history

My professor began discussing branch cuts in class today and mentioned that he did not know the origin of the term. Does anyone know the origin of the term and perhaps a source that talks about it?

Comment: The use of "branch" in branch cut is the same as the use of the word "branch" in the sense of different branches of a function.  A branch cut is a cut in the plane made to ensure that you can choose a single valued branch of the function at hand.  So I would guess that the expression "branch of a function" came first, and that the expression "branch cut" was derived from it.